# init gmap3 using geocode

Tags: google-maps, initialization, jquery-gmap3

I am new to gmap3, is it possible to init the gmap3 using a place address?
I know generally it is done with latitude and longitude.
I have done markers with this this location name using [this](http://gmap3.net/api.html) example.
I have already gone through [this](http://www.clementlevallois.net/nesshi/gmap3/demo/mixed.html) example too, but no luck.
And also i need to zoom the places on selection, i use auto complete for this purpose.

My code is given below

```
 $('#test').gmap3(
     { action:'init',
         options:{
             address: "kerala,india"
         }
     }

 );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First use `getLatLng()` to retrieve the location, when successfull set the center:

```
   $('#test1').gmap3(
    { action : 'getLatLng',
      address:'kerala,india',
      callback : function(result){
        if (result){
          $(this).gmap3({action: 'setCenter', args:[ result[0].geometry.location ]},
                        {action: 'setZoom', args:[ 12]});
      } else {
      alert('not found !');
      }}});
```

Comment: Thanks, is there any way to put the auto zoom? i mean to cover the full location?

Comment: You must know the latLngBounds of the location to achieve it.

Answer (score 2):

```
var add="kerala,india";
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

geocoder.geocode({ address: add, region: 'no' },
function (results, status) {
 if (status.toLowerCase() == 'ok') {
    // Get center
    var coords = new google.maps.LatLng(
        results[0]['geometry']['location'].lat(),
        results[0]['geometry']['location'].lng()
    );
    //alert(coords);
    $map.gmap3("get").setCenter(coords);
    $map.gmap3("get").setZoom(12);
    addMarker(coords);
 }
 else {
    alert("address not found");
 }
}    

function addMarker(marker) {
    $map = $('#googleMap');
    if (marker) {
        $map.gmap3(
            { action: 'init',
                options: {
                    center: eval(marker),
                    zoom: 12,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                }
            },
            { action: 'addMarker',
                latLng: eval(marker),
                options: {
                    draggable: true,
                    icon: new google.maps.MarkerImage('http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/marker.png')
                },
                events: {
                    dragend: function (mark) {
                        updateMarker(mark);
                    }
                }
            });
    }
}
```

Using above code you can get latitude/longitude also and drag searched location marker.

Answer (score 1):

This feature will be in next version (5.0), current is not updated,

here is a working code :

```
  $('#test1').gmap3({ 
    action : 'getLatLng',
    address:'kerala,india',
      callback : function(result){
        if (result){
          $(this).gmap3({
            action: "init",
            options:{
                center: result[0].geometry.location,
                zoom: 12
            } 
        });
      } else {
        alert('not found !');
      }
    }
});
```

notice, if your map is already initialized, you can use in the callback

```
    $(this).gmap3("get").setCenter(result[0].geometry.location);
    $(this).gmap3("get").setZoom(12);
```

Comment: Thank you @jbdemonte I was looking for a simple way to center a marker, and here I found it. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code as well:

```
var markerData = [];
markerData.push({ address: 'kerala,india', data: '' });
$('#test').gmap3({
   action: 'addMarkers',
   markers: markerData
   }
);
```